Revoke data mutable
we are trying to make our metadata not mutable and change it, but when i press update i get error in transaction everytime, here is link for transaction
https://solana.fm/tx/kRBdxVHqyyeDkBF2zTAoPDf6xvwS9fu4KefnMorzJ9Lm4u92VcX7fPEAb5xmipEfAyhYJZywDhxsnGkuWMmSzxk?cluster=mainnet-beta

From the tx logs, it seems that you are trying to remove a verified creator, which is causing the error.
0x5e is 94 in decimal notation which is the CannotAdjustVerifiedCreator error
When creating the token you can mark the metadata as mutable by setting the isMutable field to false
await createFungibe(umi, {
        mint,
        name: "",
        uri: "",
        updateAuthority: publicKey(umi.identity.publicKey),
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(5.5),
        tokenOwner: umi.identity.publicKey,
        isMutable: false, // ! here
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

To update an already existing token use the updateV1 to make the token metadata immutable
const initialMetadata = await fetchMetadataFromSeeds(umi, { mint })

await updateV1(umi, {
  mint,
  authority: updateAuthority,
  data: { ...initialMetadata, name: 'Updated Asset' },
  primarySaleHappened: true,
  isMutable: false, // ! immutable metadata
  // ...
}).sendAndConfirm(umi)

ref for creating: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/mint#create-helpers
ref when updating: https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata/update

Is it possible to update using some site, without coding? We created token without writing any code

If there are sites that support this then yes. If you fi want to start from the start Smithii token creator provides this https://tools.smithii.io/token-creator/solana
